# How pip determine a python package version

Tags: python, pip

When I use pip to install a package from source, it will generates a version number for the package which I can see using 'pip show '. But I can't find out how that version number is generated and I can't find the version string from the source code. Can someone tell me how the version is generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version number that `pip` uses comes from the `setup.py` (if you `pip install` a file, directory, repo, etc.) and/or the information in the PyPI index (if you `pip install` a package name). (Since these two must be identical, it doesn't really matter which.)

It's recommended that packages make the same string available as a `__version__` attribute on their top-level module/package(s) at runtime that they put in their setup, but that isn't required, and not every package does.

And if the package doesn't expose its version, there's really no way for you to get it. (Well, unless you want to grub through the `pip` data trying to figure out which package owns a module and then get its version.)

---

Here's an example:

In the source code for `bs4` (BeautifulSoup4), the [`setup.py`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/setup.py) file has this line:

```
version = "4.3.2",
```

That's the version that's used, directly or indirectly, by `pip`.

Then, inside [`bs4/__init__.py`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py), there's this line:

```
__version__ = "4.3.2"
```

That means that Leonard Richardson is a nice guy who follows the recommendations, so I can `import bs4; print(bs4.__version__)` and get back the same version string that `pip show beautifulsoup4` gives me.

But, as you can see, they're two completely different strings in completely different files. If he wasn't nice, they could be totally different, or the second one could be missing, or named something different.

---

The OpenStack people came up with a nifty library named [PBR](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/) that helps you manage version numbers. You can read the linked doc page for the full details, but the basic idea is that it either generates the whole version number for you out of git, or verifies your specified version number (in the `metadata` section of `setup.cfg`) and appends the `dev` build number out of git. (This relies on you using [Semantic Versioning](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/semver.html) in your `git` repo.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm curious about where the rest of the version string comes from. For example, openstack cinder has version = 2014.2 in setup.cfg (https://github.com/openstack/cinder/blob/master/setup.cfg). After pip install -e ~/cinder, its version in pip show is 2014.2.0.0b4.dev83. I'm wondering how '.0.0b4.dev83' comes from.

Comment: @tvbinstinct I believe all of the OpenStack projects use [PBR](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbr/) to manage version numbers, and it does things like try to extract version info out of the DVCS repo version and tag to append to the specified version number, but I'm not really sure; I've never read the docs or played with it to see what it's doing.

Comment: @tvbinstinct: Aha, found it. Let me update the answer with full details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the version number in code, tools [such as `setuptools-scm`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) may use tags from version control. Sometimes the magic is not directly visible. For example [PyScaffold uses it](https://pyscaffold.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.2/features.html#versioning-and-git-integration), but in the project's root folder's `__init__.py` one may just see:

```py
import pkg_resources

try:
    __version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution(__name__).version
except:
    __version__ = "unknown"
```

If, for example, the highest version tag in Git is 6.10.0, then `pip install -e .` will generate a local version number such as `6.10.0.post0.dev23+ngc376c3c` (`c376c3c` being the short hash of the last commit) or `6.10.0.post0.dev23+ngc376c3c.dirty` (if it has uncommitted changes).

Answer (score 0):

For more complicated strings such as `4.0.0rc1`, they are usually hand edited in the `PKG-INFO` file. Such as:

```
# cat ./<package-name>.egg-info/PKG-INFO 
...
Version: 4.0.0rc1
...
```

This make it unfeasible to obtain it from within any python code.